# MatTooltip does not display when used inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I am trying to display a list of cards that will update dynamically as the data in another service is updated. Each card should have a tool tip that displays the item's name when the user hovers over it.

Originally my code was as follows:

```
<div class="bankItemsContainer" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <div class="bankItem" *ngFor="let item of GetBankItems()">
        <mat-card class="card-picture" matTooltip="{{item.name}}">
            <mat-card-title fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="{{item.icon}}"></mat-icon>
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-footer style="text-align: center;">{{ item.quantity }}</mat-card-footer>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the tooltip was not being shown when I hovered over the card.

After some research I was able to find out that calling a function doesn't work well with ngFor and thus causes issues for the matTooltip since the items are constantly being re rendered.

I then changed the ngFor to use the property from the service that need to access:

```
*ngFor="let item as playerService.playerSave.bank.items"
```

This did not fix it. I read that using an observable should help so I set up an observable around the value from the service.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bankItems$ = of(this.playerService.playerSave.bank.items);
  }
```

And changed the ngFor to:

```
*ngFor="let item of bankItems$ | async; let i=index"
```

Again the tooltip still doesn't show when I mouse over the card.

I feel like I have run out of things to try and I am not sure how to ultimately make this work.

Comment: Adding TrackBy function solved my problem with ngFor and matTooltips not showing. https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I tried your code to replicate your issue. The issue is that you were missed the id attribute to the tooltip.

**<mat-card class="card-picture" #tooltip="matTooltip"
matTooltip="{{item.name}}">**

I tried it as mentioned below.

```
<div class="bankItemsContainer" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <div class="bankItem" *ngFor="let item of GetBankItems()">
        <mat-card class="card-picture" #tooltip="matTooltip"
        matTooltip="{{item.name}}">
            <mat-card-title fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="{{item.icon}}"></mat-icon>
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-footer style="text-align: center;">{{ item.quantity }}</mat-card-footer>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where my tooltips weren't showing up inside of an `*ngFor` loop but it turned out that I was using several functions within my template which caused a lot of re-rendering every time my mouse moved. Once I removed the functions and replaced with properties, it was resolved. [This article](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) explains more details about why you shouldn't use function calls in your angular template expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the `MatTooltipModule` into the module that declares the component?

Your markup works in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kbs-so-mattooltip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-overview-example.html

Comment: Yes MatTooltipModule is imported in the module for the component.